# How to pass an SVD file as an argument to IDA Pro in the command line (batch mode)?

Tags: ida, disassembly, binary-analysis, idapython, arm

I am trying to disassemble a few Arm Cortex-M3 .elf binaries and run a custom IDAPython script (script.py) from the command line (in batch mode). I have been able to do that with the following command:

```
/path_to_idapro/idat -B -parm:ARMv7-M -logfile.log -S"/path_to_script/script.py arg1" elf_to_disassemble
```

However, I need to load an SVD file before running script.py so that my analysis will be complete. In IDA Pro GUI, I do the following:

- Edit > Plugins > SVD file management
- Select the SVD file

How can I pass the SVD file (e.g., /path_to_SVD/STM32F103.svd) as an argument to my previous command?

I have already searched the command line switches of IDA Pro https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml, and to my understanding, there isn’t such an option.

I am currently using IDA Pro v7.6 in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can run plugins from a script as follows:

```py
import ida_loader

arg = 0
ida_loader.load_and_run_plugin("svdimport", arg)
```

Where `arg` has `size_t` type. This normally allows you to select plugin modes, but does not allow you to pass strings to your plugin.

Thus, I think there are two not-so-pleasant options:

- generate idb manually and only then analyse it in batch mode (doesn't make much sense when analysing at scale)
- use a custom SVD Loader Plugin with a hardcoded file value or passed through configuration file (check out [this](https://github.com/h2lab/SVD-Loader) and [this](https://github.com/Accenture/FirmLoader) as an input pointers)